# EmguCV opens the camera but doesn't view frames in ImageBox

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to make a simple `openCV` camera application with `c#` on windows x64Bit.

To do so, I copied `cvextern.dll`, `Emgu.CV.dll`, `Emgu.CV.UI.dll`, `Emgu.Util.dll` and all `opencv_*.dll` files to the solution's debug folder.
I add the files `Emgu.CV.dll`, `Emgu.CV.UI.dll` and `Emgu.Util.dll` as refrence.

In the form `CameraCapture` when I click the button `btnStart` the camera frames shoud be displayed in the Imagebox `CamImageBox`.

here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace CameraCapture
{
    public partial class CameraCapture : Form
    {
        private Capture capture;
        private bool captureInProgress;

        public CameraCapture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
            CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region if capture is not created, create it now
            if (capture == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    capture = new Capture();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            if (capture != null)
            {
                if (captureInProgress)
                {  

                    btnStart.Text = "Start!"; //
                    Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                    Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
                }

                captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
            }
        }

        private void ReleaseData()
        {
            if (capture != null)
                capture.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't show any error while building the project. The problem is that when I run the project and press the button `btnStart` nothing is displayed in the Imagebox `CamImageBox`.

The code shows me no errors. The camera is working fine. When I run the project My camera's light turn on "camera starts working when I run the project" But I don't recieve any picture in the Imagebox.

Is there something I'm missing with the files, project configration?

Comment: You're missing a couple of things? you need add more things like, Detecting a camera, initializing a `d://show` convert it to ImageShource/BitMapSource (To display in ImageBox) or and capturing a frame from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to your 'using' add 'Using.Emgu.CV.UI'..just try that